# Error:mysqld.service: Start request repeated too quickly. On manjaro

Tags: mysql, linux, archlinux, manjaro

Yesterday I updated my manjaro. I had many problems since then.

Firstly, I type

```
systemctl status mysqld.service
```

to start MySQL, but it errors out with

```
mysqld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
```

I has found many suggestions but they doesn't work.

I already have tried:

- Check the permission of the MySQL data directory using the below command. The ownership should be `mysql:mysql` and the directory permission should be 700.

  ```
  ls -ld /var/lib/mysql/
  ```
- Check the permission of databases inside the MySQL data directory using the below command. The ownership should be `mysql:mysql` for all the files inside that directory.

  ```
  ls -lh /var/lib/mysql/
  ```
- Check the listening network TCP ports using the command

  ```
  netstat -ntlp
  ```
- Check the MySQL log files for any error using:

  ```
  cat /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
  ```
- Try to start MySQL using

  ```
  mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cf
  ```

My Error:

```
dong@dong-manjaro  /home/dong   systemctl status mysqld.service                                                                          13:30:33 
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-08-22 13:30:29 CST; 6s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 8006 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8027 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 8027 (code=exited, status=127)

8月 22 13:30:29 dong-manjaro systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
8月 22 13:30:29 dong-manjaro systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
8月 22 13:30:29 dong-manjaro systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
8月 22 13:30:29 dong-manjaro systemd[1]: **mysqld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.**
8月 22 13:30:29 dong-manjaro systemd[1]: **mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.**
8月 22 13:30:29 dong-manjaro systemd[1]: **Failed to start MySQL Server.**
```

Comment: Wait, Wait,Wait

Answer (score 12):

I have faced same issue and solved this problem like that:

if `/var/log/mysql` folder not exists:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql
```

and then give permission this folder:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql

sudo systemctl stop mysql

sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: the best so far

Comment: /var/log/mysql should probably be /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 4):

Ran into similar issue.Follow steps(Sql server Version: '8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3')

```
 1. Edit file: mysqld.cnf under directory: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
 2. Ensure that below basic settings are made in file mysqld.cnf and save it.
 # * Basic Settings
 user       = mysql
 pid-file   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 socket     =   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 port       = 3306
 datadir    = /var/lib/mysql
 # setting for localhost
 bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
 mysqlx-bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
 log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
 server-id      = 1
 log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
 max_binlog_size    = 100M
 3. Check error log files under directory: /var/log/mysql 
 4. Remove all log files: Cd /var/log/mysql $ sudo rm -R error*
 5. Start mysql server: $ sudo systemctl start mysql.service
 6. Check status of mysql server: $ sudo systemctl status mysql.service
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed like this:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

For us, it was to `chown` the logfile:

```
[root@tree ~]# ls -alh /var/log/mysqld.log 
-rw-r----- 1 root logs 8.3K Apr 20 02:17 /var/log/mysqld.log
[root@tree ~]# chown mysql: /var/log/mysqld.log 
[root@tree ~]# systemctl start mysqld
[root@tree ~]# systemctl status mysqld
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-04-20 15:32:01 UTC; 20s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 28339 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28313 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28342 (mysqld)
   Memory: 43.3G
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─28342 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Got rid of the same failure.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04.

You need to make the `mysql` user the owner of `datadir` and `log_error` directories by executing:

```
sudo chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
```

Path to directories may differ. You can find appropriate paths at configuration file, which is located at: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to comment one line (binlog_expire_logs_seconds=259200) in /etc/mysql/my.cnf .
It was pointed out to me by running

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

when I've got:

```
mysqld: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 22.
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```